# Evaluating $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+\sin(4x)}{2x-\sin(x)}$ without l'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

The solution with l'Hôpital is quite simple.

$lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+\sin(4x)}{2x-\sin(x)}=\frac{(x+\sin(4x))'}{(2x-\sin(x))'}=\frac{1+4\cos(4x)}{2-\cos(x)}=\frac{1+4}{2-1}=5$

But I don't know how to face the question without using l'Hôpital. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try expanding sin(4x) and sin (x) using Taylor's expansion and see what you get.

Comment: I never learnt L'Hopital's rule, and for these limits I always use $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to zero.You can convert to this form via division in this question.

Comment: @Rohan I'm in high school and I didn't get to series yet. But I hope to be able to do so in a couple of months :-) Cheers!

Comment: @E.H.E typing mistake, yes, $\frac {\sin x}x$ goes to $1$ as $x$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+\sin(4x)}{2x-\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x}{4x}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}{\frac{2x}{4x}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$$
and use the fact
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}=1$$

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+\sin(4x)}{2x-\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{x}{4x}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}{\frac{2x}{4x}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sin(4x)}{4x}}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}+1}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{\frac{5}{4}}{\frac{1}{4}}=5$ 


Never would've guessed that it would be this simple. So that's how you solve such questions. Thanks and have a nice day!